# PayPal REST APIs > Create Order > How to add experience_context (e.g. return_url and cancel_url)

Tags: rest, paypal

**Update (Solution):**

When the experience_context is added to the request body, the PayPal-Request-Id seems to be become mandatory in the Header of the curl Request.

```php
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Content-Type: application/json',
    'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken(),
    'PayPal-Request-Id: ' . uniqid()
)
```

(In PHP) I try to create a simple (sample) order according to the [documentation of the REST APIs](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/) (see Sample Request)

The request with the following simple data works fine:

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": 100
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

When I try to add the experience_context (https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/orders/v2/#definition-paypal_wallet_experience_context) according to the Sample Request of the documentation, I get the following answer

The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request

```
{
    "intent": "CAPTURE",
    "purchase_units": [
        {
            "amount": {
                "currency_code": "EUR",
                "value": 100
            }
        }
    ],
    "payment_source": {
        "paypal": {
            "experience_context": {
                "brand_name": "testmememe",
                "cancel_url": "https://example.com/cancelUrl",
                "return_url": "https://example.com/returnUrl"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**What am I doing wrong?**

My PayPal-Class:

```php
<?php

class PayPal
{
    
    const CLIENT_ID = 'client_id';
    const CLIENT_SECRET = 'client_secret';
    const BASE_URL =  'https://api-m.sandbox.paypal.com';
    

    const SESSION_KEY = 'paypal_api';
    
    public function __construct()
    {
        if(!isset($_SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY])) $_SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY] = array();
    }
    
    public function getAccessToken():string
    {
        if (isset($SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY]['access_token']) && isset($SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY]['access_token_expiration_time']) && $SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY]['access_token_expiration_time'] > time()) return $SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY]['access_token'];
        
        $curl = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => self::BASE_URL . '/v1/oauth2/token',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Accept: application/json',
                'Accept-Language: en_US'
            ),
            CURLOPT_USERPWD => self::CLIENT_ID . ':' . self::CLIENT_SECRET,
            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => 'grant_type=client_credentials'
        );
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl))
        {
            print_r(curl_error($curl));
            curl_close($curl);
            return '';
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        $data = json_decode($result, true);
        if (!isset($data['access_token']) || !isset($data['expires_in'])) return '';
        $access_token = $data['access_token'];
        $SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY]['access_token'] = $access_token;
        $SESSION[self::SESSION_KEY]['access_token_expiration_time'] = time() + $data['expires_in'];
        return $access_token;
    }
    
    public function createOrder()
    {
        $amount_obj = new stdClass();
        $amount_obj->currency_code = 'EUR';
        $amount_obj->value = 100.00;
        
        $object = new stdClass();
        $object->amount = $amount_obj;
        
        $experience_context = new stdClass();
        $experience_context->brand_name = 'testmememe';
        $experience_context->cancel_url = "https://example.com/cancelUrl";
        $experience_context->return_url = "https://example.com/returnUrl";
        
        $data = array(
            'intent' => 'CAPTURE',
            'purchase_units' => array(
                $object
            ),
            'payment_source' => array(
                'paypal' => array(
                    'experience_context' => $experience_context
                )
            )
        );
        $data_string = json_encode($data);
        
        $curl = curl_init();
        $options = array(
            CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
            CURLOPT_FAILONERROR => true,
            CURLOPT_URL => self::BASE_URL . '/v2/checkout/orders',
            CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
                'Content-Type: application/json',
                'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->getAccessToken()
            ),

            CURLOPT_POST => true,
            CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data_string
        );
        curl_setopt_array($curl, $options);
        $result = curl_exec($curl);
        if (curl_errno($curl))
        {
            print_r(curl_error($curl));
            curl_close($curl);
            return '';
        }
        curl_close($curl);
        $data = json_decode($result, true);
        if (isset($data['status']) && $data['status'] === 'CREATED' && is_array($data['links']))
        {
            foreach ($data['links'] as $link)
            {
                if ($link['rel'] === "approve")
                {
                    $url = $link['href'];
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        var_dump($data);
        echo $url;
    }
}
```

Aufruf:

```php
$paypal_obj = new PayPal;

$paypal_obj->createOrder();
```

Comment: The request body JSON in your question is correct, and should not return a 400 when transmitted correctly. Show the entire API response

Comment: @PrestonPHX Thank you! I added ```$result = curl_exec($curl); var_dump($result);``` Output: ```bool(false) The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request```

Comment: curl_error($curl)

Comment: curl_error($curl) => ```string(49) "The requested URL returned error: 400 Bad Request"```

Comment: I found the error: In the Header the PayPal-Request-Id is required. Don't know why ```-H "PayPal-Request-Id: 7b92603e-77ed-4896-8e78-5dea2050476a"```